# How do I construct complex django query statements?

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I am not very familiar with SQL and so trying to make more complex calls via Django ORM is stumping me.  I have a Printer model that spawns Jobs and the jobs receive statuses via a State model with a foreign key relationship to it. The jobs status is determined by the most recent state object associated with it.  This is so I can track the history of states of jobs throughout its life cycle.  I want to be able to determine which Printers have successful jobs associated with them.

```
from django.db import models


class Printer(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=120) 


class Job(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    printer = models.ForeignKey(
        Printer,
        related_name='jobs',
        related_query_name='job'
    )
    
    def set_state(self, state):
        State.objects.create(state=state, job=self)

    @property
    def current_state(self):
        return self.states.latest('created_at').state


class State(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.SmallIntegerField()
    job = models.ForeignKey(
        Job,
        related_name='states',                                          
        related_query_name='state'
    )
```

I need a QuerySet of Printer objects that have at least one related job with its most recent (latest) state object which has `State.state == '200'`.  Is there a way to construct a compound call which will achieve this using the database and not having to pull in all Job objects to run python iterations on?  Perhaps a custom manager?  I've been reading posts about Subquery and Annotation and OuterRef, but these ideas are just not sinking in in a way that is showing me a path.  I need them explained like I'm 5. They are very unpythonic statements..

The naive python way to describe what I want:

```
printers = []
for printer in Printer.objects.all():
    for job in printer.jobs.objects.all():
        if job.states.latest().state == '200':
            printers.append(printer)
printers = list(set(printers))
```

But with the least number of DB round trips possible.  Help!

edit: further question, what's the best way to filter Jobs based on the current state.  Since Job.current_state is a calculated property it cannot be used in a QuerySet filter.  But, again, I don't want to have to pull in all Job objects.

Answer (score 0):

Took about two days to sink in, but I think I have an answer using annotation and Subqueries:

```
state_sq = State.objects.filter(job=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')                                                                        

successful_jobs = Job.objects.annotate(          
    latest_state=Subquery(state_sq.values('state')[:1])        
).filter(printer=OuterRef('pk'), latest_state='200')
                                                                        
printers_with_successful_jobs = Printer.objects.annotate(                                   
    has_success_jobs=Exists(successful_jobs)                           
).filter(has_success_jobs=True)
```

And further, I constructed a custom manager to return `latest_state` by default.

```
class JobManager(models.Manager):                                       
    def get_queryset(self):                                             
        state_sq = State.objects.filter(                                
            object_id=OuterRef('pk')                                    
        ).order_by('-created_at')                                       
                                                                        
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(                         
            latest_state=Subquery(state_sq.values('state')[:1])         
        )

class Job(models.Model):
    objects = JobManager()
    ...
```